# Connection to an external wifi network is established but pings aren't going through - using ipv6

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, ping, wpa-supplicant

So I am using a WiFi chip on an embedded board, and I set it up as a supplicant to connect to an external network and i'm able to to do it fine, but it just pings don't go through and i'm not sure if it has to do with some weird security layers in the network preventing the pings.

```
// embedded wifi module's interface
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:7f:61:a0:41
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:7fff:fe61:a041/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000
          RX bytes:11332 (11.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1468 (1.4 KiB)


// host machine's interface

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d07:dd6b:dc52:8b85%26
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.100.32
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.100.1
```

I sent the pings as follows from the wifi module:

```
ping6 -I wlan0 fe80::7d07:dd6b:dc52:8b85%26
```

but it results in 100% packet loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zone index shown for link-local address **depends on the sender.** The part following the `%` tells the OS which *local* interface to send the packets through – the sender doesn't actually know which remote interface will receive them.

So in your case, the correct address is `fe80::7d07:dd6b:dc52:8b85%wlan0`. The "-I" option is not necessary because the address has the same information:

```
ping6 fe80::7d07:dd6b:dc52:8b85%wlan0
```

And in the opposite direction, from Windows host (where WiFi is interface #26) to Linux board:

```
ping fe80::203:7fff:fe61:a041%26
```

(When writing programs using Socket API, getaddrinfo() accepts both named and numeric zone specifiers, but in other situations you'll need to manually translate it using if_nametoindex("wlan0").)

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm still uncertain as to why adding `-i` wouldn't work but `%wlan0` would given they technically mean the same thing, no? I was able to send pings but I don't see them in Wireshark for some reason with a filter of `ipv6`

Comment: also, a couple more follow ups: any reason you used `ping6` for sending from linux board to the host? I tried that but didn't work but `ping` ended up working. Secondly, what interface does `%26` refer to?

Comment: 1) You also had `%26` in your attempt, which probably took precedence over the `-I` option, resulting in the pings being set over the wrong interface. 2) Based on your own example, I assumed you had an older Linux distro which did not have the dual-version `ping` command yet. (Linux ping only got IPv6 support very recently, older distros had separate ping and ping6.)

Comment: 3) On the Windows host where you ran the "ipconfig", `%26` refers to the exact same "Wi-Fi" interface that it's listed under. (It wouldn't make sense any other way!) You can run `netsh interface ipv6 show interface` to get a table of interfaces and their indexes. However, when you tried to ping it from the Linux board, the same `%26` now had a completely different meaning – run `ip link` to figure out which interface had index 26 on Linux.

Comment: 1) I saw examples online that you could either explicitly include the interface via `-i` or use `%`. 2) so `ping` command in latest linux distros includes both ipv4 & ipv6? 3) I was curious as to why use an `index` as opposed to a name like we did on linux side? I see `Wi-Fi` has an index of `26` on windows. On linux, I ran `ip link` and do numbers on the far-left refer to index of interfaces? there's no such index for 26